# How to detect what is the model of the view and where its getting populated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm learning a C# ASP.NET MVC application and I'm having a hard time walking backwards from the view to the code that executes a stored procedure that populates the model class. This is complicated (for me) by the fact that it uses Castle for IoC, so I can't just search for `new [Classname]`.

Any help is appreciated.

I'll post a more in-depth example soon, but for now I'll simply explain it this way:

One has a `View` which refers to a `@model`. That model is a class that was populated via a Controller by calling a stored procedure (or executing inline SQL) and passed to the View.

In simplest terms, my question is:

- When I see `@model` in a View, how do I figure out which class @model refers to,
- How do I find the place where that class got populated with data before it got passed to the View?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I figure out which class @model refers to?

The same way that you can go to the definition of a code element in `.cs` files, you can do that in `.cshtml` files as well. Click on the name of the type in front of `@model` and press <kbd>F12</kbd> or *Right click → Go To Definition* to see the definition of the type or choose *Go To Implementation* to see the implementation if available.

If you don't have `@model` the view class is deriving from `WebViewPage<dynamic>` the model for the view is `dynamic`. If you have `@model Something` the view class is deriving from `WebViewPage<Something>` and the model for the view is `Something`.

Assuming you have a `SampleModel` class in `SampleProject.Models` namespace, the following ways are some ways that you can declare `@model` for the `Index.cshtml` view which is located in `Home` folder, under `Views` folder:

***Without any @model***

```
<div> Hello! </div>
```

***FullName in View***

```
@model SampleProject.Models.SampleModel
<div> Hello! </div>
```

***Using and Name in View:***

```
@using SampleProject.Models
@model SampleModel
<div> Hello! </div>
```

***Namespace in web.config and Name in View***

Having a namespace entry in`web.config` in root of the project, or in `Views` folder or in your view folder (in the example, `Home` folder):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      ...
      <add namespace="SampleProject.Models" />
      ...
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

And the name in view file:

```
@model SampleModel
<div> Hello! </div>
```

#### How do I find the place where that class got populated with data before it got passed to the View?

In short, at design time, the view doesn't know where its data come from, while action knows which view is going to return. At run-time, view knows which action has returned it.

**Design time**

In MVC, the View doesn't belong to a controller and any action of a controller can return the view simply. So `View` at design time doesn't have a parent controller/action, while the action knows which view they are going to return.

However in simple cases, which you have a 1-1 relation between views and actions, a view in the following path `Views\Home\Index` usually is returned by `Index` action of `HomeController` class.

In simple cases, when you are coding in view, if you *Right Click* and choose *Go To Controller*, it goes to the controller class based on the folder name of the view. When you are coding in controller and *Right Click* in body of name of an *Action* and choose *Go To View*, it goes to the view having the same name as your action in a folder with the same name as your controller (without controller suffix) under views folder.

**Run-time**

At run-time, each view knows what controller/action has returned it:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
@ViewContext.Controller
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: You nailed it when you said it's easier to figure these things out at run-time than design-time. Just as an aside, I think 2 things that complicate my company's application are: 1) we use the CQRS architecture, and 2) Castle makes it difficult to figure out (at design time) which class is being instantiated because Visual Studio displays "0 references" above class declarations. To add 1 more thing to your answer, in VS's Debug Mode you can use the "Diagnostics Tools" pane to filter on such things as "ADO.NET" to find the stored procedure(s) and inline SQL being used to populate a class/model.